# Xamarin: The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly. The process cant access the file exception

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a xamarin project. When i build the project i get following error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'D:\my\csharpprojects\sampleXamarin\sampleForm\sampleForm.Android\obj\Debug\81\sampleForm.Android.dll'
>   because it is being used by another process.
>
> Server stack trace:     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share)    at
>   Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName,
>   ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName,
>   ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute(IList`1& thrownExceptions)
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.Execute()    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() iliidit.Android

I tried restarting visual studio. Even tried restarting Windows. But no luck. Not sure why the compiler is unable to access the sampleForm.Android.dll file.

Toolset configuration

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017  Version 15.9.6
  VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.6+28307.344 Microsoft .NET Framework
  Version 4.7.03056
- Xamarin   4.12.3.79 (d15-9@260fa6a34) Visual Studio extension to
  enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
- Xamarin Designer   4.16.13 (45a16efd4) Visual Studio extension to
  enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
- Xamarin Templates   1.1.128 (6f5ebb2) Templates for building iOS,
  Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.
- Xamarin.Android SDK   9.1.5.0 (HEAD/4b951a3e7) Xamarin.Android
  Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
- Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.2.1.12 (65ec520)
- Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: Have you edited any of the default xaml that was generated? Sometimes it's a syntactical error in your xaml that throws this exception.

Answer (score 1):

What happens during a Xamarin.Forms build, in this case:

1. Roslyn/Csc compiles your C# code into a .NET assembly
2. XamlC then compiles your XAML by modifying the assembly after the fact

Some process in the middle opened the file, could it be an antivirus software or Windows Defender? Does adding a [Windows Defender exclusion](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security) for your project's directory solve the problem? If you just try to build again, does it go away?

Comment: I installed VS 2019 community edition and the compilation problem solved. Earlier, I was using VS 2017 community edition. Though upgrading to VS 2019, doesn't explain how and why the compilation problem was solved.